# virtualhost for subdomain using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, virtualhost

I have uploaded source code of my product on the site .

My site name is for eg:- testcoder.com

now...the thing is i have many clients to whom i wanted to provide service but they want there domain needs to be

client1.testcoder.com
client2.testcoder.com

i have created a subdomain as well
but the basic thing is code is same for all the clients so what i did is i kept my code
under

code.testcoder.com

Now i want .htaccess virtual host in such a way that even the client uses

"client1.testcoder.com" browser needs to server the code from "code.testcoder.com"
and in the same way "client1.testcoder.com/test1.php" needs to be "code.testcoder.com/test1.php"....

i wanted to do it from .htaccess only as i am using shared hosting....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. Just make sure all the subdomains use the same document root as the `code.testcoder.com` domain. You don't need to do anything special in htaccess unless you have existing rules there to rewrite rules that are hardcoded for the host: `code.testcoder.com`